# Why when I upload a image to S3 bucket my API doesnt work?

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, nuxt.js

I am using Vue/NuxtJs as a front end and .net core 2.1 as a backend. I need to send an image to my backend and upload into an S3 Bucket. It works well in localhost, however, when I publish my API start to give errors, for example, the files become bigger and corrupted, and it is happening only with images. Someone can help?

front end

```
async onUpload() {
      this.isNew = true;
      this.showProgess = true;
      debugger;
      const file = new FormData();
      console.log(this.selectedFile.size);
      file.append("file", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
      file.append("fileType", 0);
      await this.$axios
        .$post(process.env.API_URL + `/PlanImages`, file, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          },
          onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            );
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.result.success) {
            this.uploadSuccess = true;
            this.saveDisable = false;
            this.uploadDisable = true;
            this.editedItem.fileUrl = response.result.fileURL;
            console.log(response);
          }
          this.showProgess = false;
          console.log("call one");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.showProgess = false;
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

back end

```
 public async Task<UploadPhotoModel> UploadPhoto(IFormFile files, string bucket)
        {
            var test = files.Length;
            // connecting to the client
            var client = new AmazonS3Client("accessKey", "accessSecret", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CACentral1);

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + files.FileName;


            using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                files.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);

                var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    InputStream = newMemoryStream,
                    Key = fileName,
                    BucketName = "bucket",
                    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };

                var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
            }
```

Comment: Do you receive any error messages? Can you provide more details about the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: No error message, everything goes fine, the problem is that somehow my back or front end change the size of the file, increasing it

Comment: front end- file sie =656299 - Result backend: result:
fileName: "0dc05dd8-439b-4365-b8fe-366a8052a1b3Screenshot (1).png"
fileURL: "https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/asbuiltimages/0dc05dd8-439b-4365-b8fe-366a8052a1b3Screenshot (1).png"
headers: 1193923
outros: "image/png"
size: 1193923
success: true

Comment: Something is wrong with my Amazon webapi serverless. I have tried azure blob and give the same error. I don't know if the gateway changes the size or something else